# How to improve a view containing multiple self joins used by a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, self-join

I have a very slow stored procedure (takes 5-6 minutes to get the result) contains some tables and a view. I believe it is the multiple self joins part in the view that makes the stored procedure slow. Here table A is a 700,000-row table and B is a 20-row table.

Table A

```
id    | status_key | status_date | seq
10035       2         2020-10-01    1
10035       3         2020-10-03    2
10049       2         2020-06-10    1
10049       3         2020-06-13    2
10049       4         2020-06-17    3
10049       5         2020-07-03    4
```

Table B

```
status_key | status_name 
    2      | accepted
    3      | conditionally accepted
    4      | decided
    5      | declined
```

The view

```
SELECT a1.status_key as current_status_key,
       b1.status_name as current_status_name,
       a1.status_date as current_status_date,
       a2.status_key as previous_status_key,
       b2.status_name as precious_status_name,
       a2.status_date as previous_status_date,
       a3.status_key as next_status_key,
       b3.status_name as next_status_name,
       a3.status_date as next_status_date,
       a4.status_key as next_2_status_key,
       b4.status_name as next_2_status_name,
       a4.status_date as next_2_status_date,
FROM A a1
INNER JOIN B b1 ON a1.status_key = b1.status_key
LEFT JOIN A a2 ON a1.id = a2.id AND a1.seq = a2.seq + 1
LEFT JOIN B b2 ON a2.status_key = b2.status_key
LEFT JOIN A a3 ON a1.id = a3.id AND a1.seq = a3.seq - 1
LEFT JOIN B b3 ON a3.status_key = b3.status_key
LEFT JOIN A a4 ON a1.id = a4.id AND a1.seq = a4.seq - 2
LEFT JOIN B b4 ON a4.status_key = b4.status_key
```

Desired result

```
 id  | current_status_key | current_status_name | current_status_date | previous_status_key | previous_status_name | previous_status_date | next_status_key | next_status_name | next_status_date | next_2_status_key | next_2_status_name | next_2_status_date 
10035 | 2 | accepted | 2020-10-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3 | conditionally accepted | 2020-10-03 | NULL | NULL | NULL
10035 | 3 | conditionally accepted | 2020-10-03 | 2 | accepted | 2020-10-01 | | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

How can I improve my view by rewriting this part? I'm considering using CTE to separate the above part. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead use LAG and LEAD to calculate the relevant status keys, instead of the self-joins on A. This hopefully means it only needs to read the rows from A once - but needs to be tested depending on your database/etc.

Here's an SQL example for the above. Note - SQL has been updated following the question update providing data.

```
WITH a1 AS
    (SELECT A.ID,
       A.status_key AS a1_status_key,
       A.status_date AS a1_status_date,
       LAG(A.status_key, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a2_status_key,
       LAG(A.status_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a2_status_date,
       LEAD(A.status_key, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a3_status_key,
       LEAD(A.status_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a3_status_date,
       LEAD(A.status_key, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a4_status_key,
       LEAD(A.status_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a4_status_date
     FROM A
    ) 
SELECT a1.id, 
       a1.a1_status_key as current_status_key,
       b1.status_name as current_status_name,
       a1.a1_status_date as current_status_date,
       a1.a2_status_key as previous_status_key,
       b2.status_name as previous_status_name,
       a1.a2_status_date as previous_status_date,
       a1.a3_status_key as next_status_key,
       b3.status_name as next_status_name,
       a1.a3_status_date as next_status_date,
       a1.a4_status_key as next_2_status_key,
       b4.status_name as next_2_status_name,
       a1.a4_status_date as next_2_status_date
FROM a1
    LEFT JOIN B b1 ON a1.a1_status_key = b1.status_key
    LEFT JOIN B b2 ON a1.a2_status_key = b2.status_key
    LEFT JOIN B b3 ON a1.a3_status_key = b3.status_key
    LEFT JOIN B b4 ON a1.a4_status_key = b4.status_key;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd93c807716ccd6ad9eb0063af3ab52a) using temp tables.

If the clustered index is on `id, seq` it would help a lot too I think. If table A is actually larger and has other values, a non-clustered index on those two columns, and then including the other relevant columns may be better e.g., `id, seq, status_date, status_key`.

**PREVIOUS VERSION**

```
WITH a1 AS
    (SELECT ...,
       LEAD(A.status_key, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a2_status_key,
       LAG(A.status_key, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a3_status_key,
       LAG(A.status_key, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY A.seq) AS a4_status_key
     FROM A
    ) 
SELECT a1.*, ...
FROM a1
    LEFT JOIN B b1 ON a1.status_key = b1.status_key
    LEFT JOIN B b2 ON a1.a2_status_key = b2.status_key
    LEFT JOIN B b3 ON a1.a3_status_key = b3.status_key
    LEFT JOIN B b4 ON a1.a4_status_key = b4.status_key;
```

Comment: If those dots use a lot of columns from another seqnr, there will be a lot of `LAGs` for which, I hope, DBMS will execute offsetting only once per offset value.  Another option is a materialized view instead of plain view, which will definitely improve the performance if this view is accessed multiple times, but will take additional space. Anyway, your solution is quite nice for such case of sequential items.

Comment: You are correct. I was using the dots based on the OP's (pre-edit) question where they used `SELECT ...` - so I just used the same, but if they are selecting a lot of columns from a2, a3 and a4 then yes that will be a lot of lead/lags. From their update, it seems they are using 2 for each (date, and status_key). It's worth a shot for performance I think, though indexing will help too.

Comment: Thx Sean. I used your method and tested it with data. It really worked! Now it only takes 20 seconds to run the stored procedure to return top 50 rows!